# wp_enqueue_scripts does not work

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script, wp-register-style

I am creating a theme for `Wordpress`, but the `wp_enqueue_scripts` does not work. The code that is in `functions.php` is:

```
<?php
function scripts_and_styles() {

  if ( ! is_admin() ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery' );
      wp_register_style( 'style.css',get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'style.css' );
      wp_register_style( 'bootstrap.min.css','https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min.css' );
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_and_styles');
?>
```

Other information that may help identify what is happening :

- When I insert `echo 'Oi!';` appears *Oi!* in `index.php`, as expected;
- I have to enter `<?php do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts') ?>` in `header.php`, and from what I understood this would not be necessary;
- When I call `var_dump` in `wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery' );` and in the others `wp_enqueue_script()` is 'printed' `NULL` in `index.php`;
- Anything that uses `jQuery` work on my theme (
  I believe that because I can not call it);
- I'm using `XAMPP`.

I appreciate the help ! Sorry for my english , I 'm not fluent .

> **The solution:** I was not calling wp_head() and wp_footer()

Comment: Does your theme have calls to wp_head and wp_footer?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook  Yes, it has these calls. I rummaged through various websites and forums , and I have no idea why this happens . I do exactly what is said.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook Sorry, I'm dumb, I'm  using <?php get_header() ?>!

Comment: That loads your header. Then last thing before your closing HTML head tag you also need wp_head() which is where the action fires.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `do_action` works, then the problem should be you are not calling `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in your header.php and footer.php respectively.